# Not able to send data in textfield using sendkeys

Tags: selenium, automation, appium, ui-automation, appium-android

When I am trying to enter the data in email text field then it is showing me this error: `Cannot set the element to 'F1@yopail.com'. Did you interact with the correct element?`

but when I am using `click()` function it is clicking on the exact same text field. I don't know why it is giving me this error. If `xpath` is wrong then how it is able to click on the same element.

Here is my code :

```java
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import javax.swing.Action;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;

import io.appium.java_client.MobileElement;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidElement;

public class Testcase extends AppiumTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException
    {
         AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> driver=Capabilities();
        // Thread.sleep(20000);
         driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20,TimeUnit.SECONDS) ;
         // Sign in page
         driver.findElementByXPath("//android.view.View[@index='7']").click();  
        WebElement email= driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.EditText[@index='2']");
        email.click();
        email.sendKeys("F1@yopail.com");
         
        }
}
```

Comment: what is the URL?

Comment: http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub I am automating android application